# How was Abraham Whistler still alive in Blade II?

Tags: plot-explanation, blade, blade-ii

- At the end of Blade I, Whistler unambiguously committed suicide. The whole thing had a very dramatic tone to it. It is implied that he got tortured *& bitten* by the vampire attack squad right before. However, it's not really definite that he was bitten. Why do i say that?

  - First off, Deacon Frost said himself he wouldn't bite him (maybe the other subordinates did though disobeying Frost).
  - When Blade returned back to find Whistler all beaten up, he said "We can cure the wounds". I believe this scene was overly dramatized by the production for the audience. Whistler replies that he's "too far gone" and insists that Blade gives him his gun and we hear the gunshot in the background, implying that Whistler did in fact commit suicide. Remember, Blade's gun had silver rounds, so no matter what he was at the time, human or vampire, he would die from it.
- Now in Blade II, Whistler has come back to life somehow. Blade's been chasing him through Russia, Romania and finally finds him in Prague, Czech Republic. Why would vampires go through all that trouble though for Whistler? Whistler only says that they enjoyed torturing him..

Now what i make up of all of this. The production simply wanted to make something up and they improvised as they went along. So they brought Whistler in the sequel, since he and Blade had a good chemistry and due to the first movie's success. Still it's very (too much i think) fake to see Whistler come up in this movie, since it was made **completely clear** that he killed himself in the first movie. It's like forget anything that make sense in the world and just bring him back. And Blade II is a great movie, not a nonsense movie, so such a big plot-hole is just too big imo.

What did really happen? Am i missing something? If anybody knows, kindly let us know.

Comment: "since it was made **completely clear** that he killed himself" - well, there was the sound of a gun firing off-screen, so how is that "completely clear?"  Do we know that his arm wasn't grabbed by a vampire as he tried to shoot? Do we know that the gun wasn't taken from him and intentionally discharged by a vampire? Do we know that he did shoot himself, but was still not quite dead when bitten?  We don't know any of that, because it was never shown, and his death was never confirmed, so I'd challenge the basic premise of this. Not enough to down-vote, though.

Comment: Agreed. I'll grant that this is an unlikley thing but it''s not **unambiguous** that Whistler died in the original movie. I suspect that was what was *meant* to be implied but if you don't see it happen it's likely to get reconned in a sequel.

Comment: [*Director Guillermo Del Toro argued that no one saw Whistler shoot himself (in the DVD commentary), so he really didn't die in Del Toro's eyes;*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0187738/faq)

Comment: "Never assume someone is dead until you see the body.  And even then, you can make a mistake"

Comment: It seems people already have some good starting points for answers worth putting into actual answers rather than wasting them on a comment discussion.

Comment: Not sure there's an answer the OP will accept. It's clearly a retcon but the OP can't get suspend disbelief enough to get past it.

Comment: Hmm, also true. The question seems to be a little bit too much "That's stupid, am I right!" rather than honestly seeking for genuine input.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - Not sure how challenging the premise, which is what I was doing, translates into an answer.  If I posted that, I'd probably get dinged pretty hard for not actually answering. It seemed to be something OP would need to address, which is why I made mine a comment.

Comment: Fair enough! Answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Y’all are forgetting, we didn’t just get the “gunshot” as Blade walked away from Whistler. We see Whistler’s arm fall limb, the gun falling from his hand, as dramatic music played. The part of his body we see next to his arm is in the same position we see during his final converse with Blade. Meaning, the only way someone could’ve interceded was to have something that sounds like a gun, and shoot Whistler non lethally. Possible, but a bit of a stretch given Blade being in the state he was; on edge, adrenaline and endorphins pumping through his viens, heightening his already heightened senses as his rage bubbled to a boil. Blade would’ve smelled and heard the intruders moving Whistler out, unless they decided the gunshot was an acceptable risk, given Blade expecting to hear it, then simply remained hidden until he left. This presents the problems of Whistler continuing to turn verus continuing to bleed out, which would be dependent upon how lomg Blade takes to get ready. A long time considering he melts Silver for his bullets during his montage. Most importantly, how far of a stretch is it to believe a second group/loner just happens to show up at the exact moment to make such a deception possible, and/or that Blade doesn’t smell the presence of other/another vampire/familiar, given he could smell exactly which of the dozen people a block away were vampires by their smell.

Comment: I KNOW!!! It was 100% impossible for him to not be dead. That's what I was telling them. It was *COMPLETELY CLEAR* that he was dead! But I learned a good lesson from the responses here (and the backlash since people actually started disliking my q, because I was being "absolute" and autocratic): "It's cinema!" Anything can happen, anything that the audience finds exciting it will return for a "next episode". Nobody cares about logic (even in a kind of serious film like Blade apparently!). A little disappointed on accepted answer to be honest, but that's the way it is. It's cool.

Comment: Poor continuity dimishes a good story. That being said, I think they knew how badly they were stepping in it with Blade 2, because they omitted Whistler’s arming falling in the flashback, had the vampire with the hot pink feather boa say, “He shot himself. Then he turned. We just kept him alive.”, then mentioned his survival at nearly evey scene in the first and sencond Act. A very thin explanation the director knew wouldn’t hold water, as evidenced by his “if you don’t see a body” dodge in the DVD commentary.

Answer (score 4):

At the start of *Blade II*, Blade runs down a gang of vampires and asks one of them where Whistler is. The vampire states:

> He shot himself. Then he turned. We just kept him alive!
>
> [image: Screen cap]

Here we have confirmation that Whistler did in fact shoot himself, but he was far enough along in the process of becoming a vampire that he survived, and was then captured by other vampires.

Comment: We (I) have already confirmed that too many times here. The point is he shoots himself (in fact he shoots himself in the head - it's implied in the film) with silver bullets!

Comment: @Nik-Lz none of the answers actually confirm that he was in fact shot in the head, and looking at the quote from the movie, as long as the bullet went clear through his head it wouldnt stop him from turning into a vampire in the few seconds the body is still alive after being shot in the head :p

Comment: 1. Yes, the claim that he wasn't shot in the head isn't confirmed by anyone. (Read my comment again carefully.) I said, that it's implied that he shot his head. 2. If you are shot in the head the body is still alive? Now where did that come from? Made up? If you are shot with a silver bullet the vampire body should turn to ash (like in Blade 1), but at that point he must have been half human, half vamp, so who knows what happened. (good plot-hole to turn it into a plot to twist and invent the sequel).

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I can do without watching the film again, its been a while...

> It is revealed in the second Blade film that Whistler survived his suicide attempt to be kidnapped by another gang of vampires and taken to the Czech Republic. After killing all but one of the vampires responsible for his imprisonment, Blade frees him from suspended animation, taking him to Prague and injecting him with the "cure". During his time with them, he was repeatedly tortured to the point of death, healed, and then tortured again.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Whistler)

So, it would seem, that maybe instead of killing himself, the vampire gang interceded and the gunshot you hear is self-defense. So, no, it is not completely clear that suicide took place and Whistler didn't just reappear back from the dead for a little chemistry with Blade.

Answer (score 1):

> since it was made completely clear that he killed himself

Well, there was the sound of a gun firing off-screen, so how is that "completely clear?" Do we know that his arm wasn't grabbed by a vampire as he tried to shoot? Do we know that the gun wasn't taken from him and intentionally discharged by a vampire? Do we know that he did shoot himself, but was still not quite dead when bitten? Did a vampire with a gun shoot the gun out of Whistler's hand so he couldn't kill himself?

We don't know any of that, because it was never shown, and his death was never confirmed, so I'd challenge the basic premise of this.

If you don't see them actually die, then they're probably not dead, unless the actor demands a hefty raise to be in the next sequel.  If you see them dead, there's a good chance that they're still not (almost definitely not if it's the monster/killer in a horror movie). If the head is removed or obliterated, and we actually see it happen in all it's gory glory, that's about the only time we can be reasonably certain that someone is actually dead.

The off-screen death is often done intentionally, for the "surprise" plot-twist to come later (use of quotes because it's used so often, it's rarely a surprise any more), as a matter of fact.

[TV Tropes: Not Quite Dead (With additional links to other "not dead" tropes)](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NotQuiteDead)